# Is there a music player that will automatically mute when other audio starts playing?

Tags: windows, linux, audio, music

I find myself listening to music while I use my computer, and constantly pausing and un-pausing the music when I watch a video on youtube, open up a game, or any other task that needs audio.

Do any music players exist that will automatically mute, or pause, when other audio starts playing on your machine?

I'm using Windows 7 primarily, although I do also use Linux (Fedora 16) on my laptop, so suggestions for either OS would be appreciated.  Also, I don't mind paying a bit for an audio player, although free software would be preferred.

Comment: It's possible to record the output itself and filter your own output out of it... But I don't know if anyone has done that... Additionally since Windows XP exposes a list of programs that play stuff to the user, I wonder if that is accessible through the API. On Linux it would need to query the different sound systems like OSS and ALSA. I bet theres a way to detect what applications connect to them at a time... But all that rambling would be more for the Stackoverflow page

Comment: Microsoft MapPoint will auto-mute/pause Windows Media player when it's speaking directions in GPS mode.  But it seems very application-specific (MapPoint automating WMP).

Comment: There is an application (abandoned, I think) called Earcandy [http://launchpad.net/earcandy], which tried to accomplish that, plus some other functions.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not an answer to your question, it may solve your problem.  I find that using a music player that supports hot keys well is invaluable for situations like you are describing.  Once you master the hot keys (bit of a learning curve) you will find your situation much more enjoyable.  I use Foobar2000 as my music player.   I have all of my num keys bound to various functions.

All of these binds use Ctrl + Win + the num key listed

> Num 4 - Prev
>
> Num 5 - Play/Pause
>
> Num 6 - Next
>
> Num 7 - Seek back 10 sec
>
> Num 9 - Seek forward 10 sec
>
> Num 2 - Volume Down
>
> Num 8 - Volume Up
>
> Num Del - Delete current Song

If you are like me, you will listen to music while playing a game, but then want to turn it off if a cut scene happens, or someone starts talking to you on vent.  Since an application would have a hard time discerning when you want the music to stop, I see this as your best option.

Answer (score 1):

I am building mute.fm (http://www.mute.fm/) to solve this problem.  It requires Windows 7 or Windows 8 desktop usage, so it should work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am using mute.fm (https://github.com/jaredsohn/mutefm) (site address changed before and in case it changes again here it is its github link). Still working with latest windows 10 (20H2). Just needed to edit commands for the music player I'm using (foobar2000) and it's good to go. Thanks @JaredSohn for this great app.

In edit page for your background player need to delete any part of the command before the slash for play and pause and you're good to go.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnowQ.png)